# Why is the FTL tag "ftl-faster-than-light"?

Tags: discussion, tags

This tag format is pretty much unprecedented. Why are we using it? Is Google failing in adding two and two together here?

I understand that this TLA is pretty unfortunate given that FTL more commonly means For The Lose - and I can appreciate lack of consistency when it's intelligent to do so (= better Google sauce); I just wonder whether this is actually the reason behind the tag or not.

Comment: For the record, FTL meant 'Faster Than Light' long before 'For The Lose' came on the scene, and it refers exclusively to superluminal communications and transit in proper scifi circles. ;)

Comment: @Wikwocket I'm sure there's countless FTL TLAs, "for the lose" is the first that got to my mind.

Comment: There's also 'French the Llama'

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**FTL: Faster Than Light** is the full title of the game.  This is the way it shows up in the [Steam store](http://store.steampowered.com/app/212680/?snr=1_7_suggest__13) (and my game library...) for example.  It's also the title used [on their website](http://www.ftlgame.com/).

Comment: I think I'm the one who created the tag when I asked the first question about it, and yeah, that's exactly why I did it that way. They just titled their game weird.

Comment: As a note, while the game is often titled as above, in some places (the packaged readme, the copyright on their web page, etc) they simply call the game FTL. The full name does seem a better tag choice to me, though.